# MySQL - Update a series of grouped rows if one of them contains a value (set all products to live if even only one is in stock)

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for the concise answer to this issue. I'm trying to update a load of rows in a product table. Currently only in-stock items are set to active. I'm looking to create a quick statement that'll set any others with the same "linked_id" to active and not deleted. So far i've got here:

```
UPDATE products
SET active=1, deleted=0
WHERE stock>=1
OR warehouse_stock>=1 
GROUP BY linked_id
```

Obviously, this isnt going to work as you cant `GROUP BY` in an update statement!?

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a self join:

```
UPDATE products p INNER JOIN products pp
ON pp.linked_id = p.linked_id
SET p.active = 1, p.deleted = 0
WHERE (p.active = 0 OR p.deleted = 1) AND (pp.stock >= 1 OR pp.warehouse_stock >= 1)
```

I guess the condition for the rows to be updated is:

```
p.active = 0 OR p.deleted = 1
```

Comment: Thnks for the reply - this killed my MySQL DB. Maybe the 300,000 entries in the product table...

Comment: I guess `linked_id` is indexed (if not it should be). Another option is to put the conditions of the WHERE clause in the ON clause. But in any case a *quick statement* to update selected rows from 300000 rows under these conditions is not expcted.